# Letting a child know that it should update its state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, signals, components

I'm trying to let a child Component know that it should update its state after a prop change in the parent.

There is no state that needs to be shared between the two. The only thing that needs to happen is that the parent should somehow let the child know that it needs to update its state (literally call `setState` by itself with the info it already has).

So far I can only figure out to do in the "React"-way through the `componentWillReceiveProps` and sending some arbitrary props, like a number, to let the child know that it should call the function to set the state.

Another way would be to use signals to let the child know, but this seems a bit over the top for this situation.

So in summary:

- The parent needs to let the child know that it should call a function
- The function will update the state (`setState`) of the child
- There is no need for the child to receive any information from the parent

Can anyone help me figure out the best way to do this?

As you can see in the snippet, this is more or less the situation. I would like to know the best way to have the Child component call the `_updateState` function when the Parents props have changed (does not happen in the snippet right now).

```js
//Imagine this is the redux-container that passes the store state to the parent.
class ParentWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    
    this.state = {status: 'normal'};
  }
  
  //This would be an action to the reducer that would update the store state
  _updateStatus(){
    this.setState({status: 'updated'});
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this._updateStatus.bind(this)}>Click me</button>
      
        <Parent status={this.state.status} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Child />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Parent.propTypes = {
  status: React.PropTypes.string
};

Parent.defaultProps = {
  status: 'normal'
};

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    
    this.state = { test: 1 };
  }
  
  _updateState(){
    this.setState({test: this.state.test + 1});
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <div>Child: {this.state.test}</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ParentWrapper />,    document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

EDIT: added snippet.

Comment: If your child don't receive any information how it will know when set new state? btw `componentWillReceiveProps` is what you need

Comment: @Maxx I know that I can use `componentWillReceiveProps`. The thing is I'm only sending props because I would need the child to call a function. I'm not actually giving it any new props. That's why I was wondering if there was a better of doing things.

Comment: @Robin_f that not looks like react way. If you have such situation, then you probably doing something wrong. Could you show real example why you need this?

Comment: @Maxx I have a decoupled component that's used in different libraries that contains its own state. I need it to reset its own state after the parent changes its props.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder added snippet. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Child's state is useless in your code (state by reference is whats controlled by component itself).  You should manage counter in parent's state (and use props to render it in child) or save it in your store and connect to child.

Comment: @Maxx I usually would do that, however in this instance, the Child component comes from a separate library that holds its own state and the Parent does not actually know about all of the state that it holds. This makes it rather impossible for the state to be stored in the store. Also what I left out of the question is that there are multiples of these kinds of Childs that have different states but are rendered on the same level making it impossible to have 1 generic state that could be stored in the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `refs` to access all the methods under the child component.

See the following fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/pranesh_ravi/412j5ucw/

Here using `refs`, I'm calling a function inside the `child` which will change the state of the `child` component.

Comment: Content of answers must be on-site, not just linked. Note that Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) support React, so you don't need a fiddle at all.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My bad. Will use that in the future. Thank you!

Comment: This might be a good idea, unless anyone can tell me why this isn't a good idea? I'll leave the question open a bit longer to see if there are better answers. But so far this seems to be the best solution.

Comment: @Robin_f I use it everywhere. By this way, you'll define all your methods within the components which make it reusable. Famous React frameworks also follows the same pattern. One good example is Material-UI

Comment: @PraneshRavi could you link me to an example where they use it? I'm curious to see an implementation.

Comment: Look at this https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/DatePicker/Calendar.js#L85. 

Now you can access this child's method using `ref`

Comment: @PraneshRavi interestingly enough they don't mention these things in the documentation anywhere. This makes me wonder if they intend for these things to be used this way.

Comment: @Robin_f That is because most of the components now render based on the props passed. But, in the backstage, this will be happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125002/discussion-between-robin-f-and-pranesh-ravi).